How to generate PDFs with clickable links/TOC from texinfo files in doc directory of Emacs' source repo
Whenever I build a new version of Emacs from source, I generate PDFs from the texinfo files located in the source repository's doc directory to have up-to-date documentation that I can easily read from tablet or smartphone.
I find it more convenient than the HTML versions.
This is done by running make pdf.
However, these PDFs don't have clickable links or clickable TOC.
Only the major manuals released here, like the GNU Emacs Manual, the GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual and An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp seem to offer that functionality.
Any idea how to get it done for all the other manuals?
EDIT:
It works fine. The hyperlinks work fine, they're just not highlighted.

I’m voting to close this question because it was based on a misunderstanding, which the OP has now fixed for himself.
